# WPF - Search for Incremental Numbered Controls using Visual Basic

Tags: wpf, vb.net

First time using WPF coming from WinForm and have been adjusting fairly well however I am stumped on one procedure I used quite commonly. This was the code that I used in WinForm to autopopulate controls that were labeled like so; label1, label2, label3, etc..

```
 Dim lbl As Label
    Dim matcheslbl() As Control

    For i As Integer = 1 To 24

        matcheslbl = Me.Controls.Find("label" & i, True)
        lbl = DirectCast(matcheslbl(0), Label)

        If matcheslbl.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matcheslbl(0) Is Label Then

            lbl.Text = "Data Here"

        End If
    Next
```

How do I use the same procedure in WPF? My hierarchy layout in the form goes from WrapPanel > StackPanel > Canvas > Controls

After modifying the code to my knowledge I get hung up on the Me.Controls aspect and cant find anything after extensively searching, or im not fully understanding it. This is my modified code...

```
       For i As Integer = 1 To 24
        Dim lbl As Label
        Dim matcheslbl() As Control

        matcheslbl = Me.WrapPanel.FindName("lbl" & i)
        lbl = DirectCast(matcheslbl(0), Label)

        If matcheslbl.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matcheslbl(0) Is Label Then

            lbl.Content = "Data Here"

        End If
    Next
```

This hangs up here..

```
matcheslbl = Me.WrapPanel.FindName("lbl" & i)
```

Any help on how to accomplish my previous procedure in WPF and give a detailed description on how to achieve it since I am very new to WPF

Comment: It would help if you showed your XAML to make it easier to explain the hierarchy.

Comment: I would also like to point out that Label is a much beefier WPF control than TextBlock and if you are just providing basic text in a window you should use TextBlock instead. I personally have found zero uses for Label vs using the lighter TextBlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the intellisense on `Me.WrapPanel.FindName` you will notice it does not return an array, just a single object. I fixed your code with the following

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 24
    Dim o As Object = wpMain.FindName("Label" + i.ToString())

    DirectCast(o, Label).Content = "Data Here"
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I will test it later and report back. Also I wasn't aware that TextBlock is the object I should be using instead of label now that I have gone over to WPF. This is excellent information since I feel completely out of my element with WPF compared to WinForms but i need a more robust UI developer so it is worth it!

Comment: Just quickly reporting back that we are in business! Thank you so much for the help! I immensely appreciate the quick response and useful tip on using TextBlocks instead!